# Is there some way to bind json values to hidden values in view when json request is made via jquery-ui?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery-ui

In my view there are some hidden fields

```
        using (Html.BeginForm("AddAttendeeSuperOffice"))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.FirstName, new { id = "SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_FirstName" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.LastName, new { id = "SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_LastName" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.AppointmentId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.SuperOfficePersonId, new { id = "SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_SuperOfficePersonId" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-8 input-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.Email, new { id = "SelectedSuperOfficeEmail", @class = "form-control", PlaceHolder = "Search in SuperOffice" }) <input type='submit' id="btnEmail" class="btn btn-default" value="Add>>" />
                </div>
            </div>

        }


@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail").
                autocomplete({
                    source: '/Appointment/SuperOfficePerson',
                    minLength: 1,  
                    });   
        });
    </script>
}
```

The call to the function that jquery-ui makes is

```
public JsonResult SuperOfficePerson(string term)
{
    var persons = _connectionRepository.FindPersonsFromSuperOffice(term);
    return Json(persons.Select(p => new { label = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName, value = p.Email,p.FirstName,p.LastName,p.ExternalPersonId}), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

and when I check the response in brower this is what i get as the json response value(just an example)

```
[{"label":"test user","value":"test.user@hotmail.com","FirstName":"test","LastName":"user","ExternalPersonId":6}]
```

Now, is there something in jquery or jquery-ui that can bind those values coming as response to my hidden field values?

**For example:**

```
$('#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_FirstName').val(json value Firstname);//something like that
$('#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_LastName').val(json value Lastname);
```

This question is same as my yesterday's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531100/set-hidden-field-values-in-form-during-json-request). But I thought this will make things more clear and help for better replies.

Edit1:
According to answer from @Andrei V
**Ajax request**

In view

@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Appointment/SuperOfficePerson',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                //set your autocomplete
                $("#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail").
                    autocomplete({
                        source: data,
                        minLength: 1,
                    });

                //convert your data so you can (easily) access the properties
                var obj = {};
                obj = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_FirstName').val(obj.FirstName);
                $('#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_LastName').val(obj.LastName);
            }
        });
    });

    //$(function() {
    //    $("#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail").
    //        autocomplete({
    //            source: '/Appointment/SuperOfficePerson',
    //            minLength: 1,

    //            });   


    //    $("#SelectedAddressBookPerson").autocomplete({
    //        source: '/Appointment/AddressBookPerson',
    //        minLength: 1,
    //    });

    //});


</script>
```

}
Problem: JsonRequest method in controller gets hit when page is loading, but when i start typing in textbox, the method doesn't get hit.
In browser console

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div.col-md-offset-2>input>Previous" browserLink:37
bc.error browserLink:37
bh browserLink:37
bp browserLink:37
r.querySelectorAll.bp browserLink:37
bc browserLink:37
p.fn.extend.find browserLink:37
p.fn.p.init browserLink:37
p browserLink:37
addExtension.r browserLink:64
t.ajax.success browserLink:64
k browserLink:37
l.fireWith browserLink:37
y browserLink:37
d
```

Update 2:
What I tried

```
@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail").
                autocomplete({
                    source: function(request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/Appointment/SuperOfficePerson',
                            type: 'GET',
                            dataType:"json",
                            data:{term:request.term},
                            success: function(data) {
                                //set your autocomplete
                                //$("#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail").
                                //    autocomplete({
                                //        source: data,
                                //        minLength: 1,
                                //    });

                                //convert your data so you can (easily) access the properties
                                var obj = {};
                                obj = JSON.parse(data);
                                $('#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_FirstName').val(obj.FirstName);
                                $('#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_LastName').val(obj.LastName);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

        });
```

but now, i see all the response but autocomplete box doesn't seem to appear :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

autocomplete has a `select` function, which can be used to do something... when a value is selected.

By the way, depending on your Mvc version, you can use `@Html.IdFor` (which can be used to get the ID of an element : better in case of refactoring)

so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail").
                autocomplete({
                    source: '/Appointment/SuperOfficePerson',
                    minLength: 1, 

                    select:function(event, ui) {
                            $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.FirstName").val(ui.item.FirstName)
                           })
                    });   
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: i'm using, asp.net mvc 5, i guess its 5.1 but...what does that @Html.IdFor do?

Comment: @Biplov13 it just returns the id generated by mvc for an element.

Comment: i think there is some syntax problem in the select part, doesn't seem to work

Comment: in select it should be just `$(@Html.IdFor(m=>m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.FirstName).val(ui.item.FirstName); `

Comment: @Biplov hmmm, strange, but if it's working... fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just make an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/Appointment/SuperOfficePerson',
   type: 'GET',
   success: function (data){
       //set your autocomplete
       $("#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail").
            autocomplete({
                source: data,
                minLength: 1,  
                }); 

       //convert your data so you can (easily) access the properties
       var obj = {};
       obj = JSON.parse(data);
       $('#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_FirstName').val(obj.FirstName);
       $('#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_LastName').val(obj.LastName);
   }
})
```

Comment: this solution is fine i think

Comment: When i load the page it hits my jsonresult method in controller, but when i start typing in textbox it doesn't do anything, I'll post it as edit

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem here, but I would move the AJAX call inside a `$(document).ready(...)`.

Comment: same problem again, so whenever this page that has autocomplete gets called, the method in controller that provides the json result gets called(don't know why) then when i type something in textbox for autocomplete, then the method in contoller that generates the json values doeesn't get called. And checking the console in browser(chrome) i get the error as mentioned in edit :(

Comment: Try changing the source of your autocomplete back to your action: `source: '/Appointment/SuperOfficePerson'`.

Comment: i'll give a shot, meanwhile you can check update2, it doesn't show error on browser console, i also get response values but autocomplete box doesn't seem to appear

Comment: i tried your suggestion(changing source) still same problem as i mentioned before

Comment: Add `response(data);` as the first line in the `success` function: `success: function(data) { response(data); ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize the json into objects and iterate/search through them? Something like:

```
var myData = JSON.parse(jsonResult);
```

Then you could do something like:

```
$('#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_FirstName').val(myData.Firstname);
```

(Haven't tried the code, but it should be close)